# Flutter Volume Level Change by Button

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to create a radio application via Flutter.
However, I cannot update the slider value when I increase or decrease the volume by iPhone button. I am using volume control and audioplayers packages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. What have you tried? Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful to you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Does this not do what you want: https://pub.dev/packages/volume_control
Found that in 5 seconds of searching pub.  Please get to know the resources you have available.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the issue is detecting when the physical volume up/down buttons are pressed and updating the slider to match. I would check out [hardware_buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons).

You should be able to listen for the button being tapped using something like this (from their example)

```
StreamSubscription _volumeButtonSubscription;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _volumeButtonSubscription = volumeButtonEvents.listen((VolumeButtonEvent event) {
    // do something
    // event is either VolumeButtonEvent.VOLUME_UP or VolumeButtonEvent.VOLUME_DOWN
  });
}
```

Then use [volume_control](https://pub.dev/packages/volume_control) to get the current volume

```
// Get the current volume, min=0, max=1
double _val = await VolumeControl.volume;
```

And finally call setState to update the slider with the current volume.